# android Instant Messaging app background service on Api 26

Tags: android, background-service, android-jobscheduler

I am working on an instant messaging app that has a `background service` (`return Service.START_STICKY`) that runs 24/7 to listen for new messages. Now, due to strict limitations on background services starting in API level 26.

[**Docs**](https://android-developers.googleblog.com/2017/10/working-with-multiple-jobservices.html)

What is the best alternative for Instant Messaging apps like WhatsApp etc.

Comment: use push message.

Comment: @someFolk: I really can't remember why I give the comment above. But it probably means using some mechanism like firebase messaging. But now, the more I think about it the more it looks like an incorrect advice. Using [scheduler](https://developer.android.com/topic/performance/scheduling) is the more proper way to tackle the problem, i.e by making the scheduler to check each 15 minutes for service availability.